# How to parse IP within fields in ELK

Tags: csv, logstash, kibana, firewall, elastic-stack

I am trying to automate/ease a procedure to review firewall rules within ELK (ElasticSearch, Logstash, Kibana).
I have some data obtained from a CSV, which is structured like this:

```
Source;Destination;Service;Action;Comment
10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/16 192.168.0.0/24 23.2.20.6;10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.3;udp:53 
tcp:53;accept;No.10: ID: INC0000000001
```

My objective is to import this data within ELK by parsing each field (for subnet and/or IP address) and, if possible, add a sequential field (IP_Source1,IP_Destination2,etc) containing each one.

Is this possible, to your knowledge? How?

Thanks for any hint you may be able to provide

Comment: Can number of IP_Source<n> and IP_Destincation<n> vary? I think it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a logstash configuration  with input as file. Then use first csv filter. CSV filter should look like this.

```
filter {
    csv {
        columns => ["source", "destination", "service", "action", "comment"]
        separator => ";"
    }
}
```

Next filter will need to be ruby filter.

```
filter { 
    ruby { 
       code => "
          arr = event.get(source).split('')
          arr.each.with_index(1) do |a, index|
               event.set(ip_source+index, a)
          end
       "
    }
}
```

Final will be output to elasticsearch.

I have not tested code. But I am hoping this shuld give you good hints.

Comment: Thanks a lot nitzien, i'll test your script and let you know if it works. And yes, the number of Sources and Destinations should vary between fields. Thanks again.

Comment: I have not tested code. So, there might be some minor tweaking required. :)

Comment: Hello nitzien. I have tested your code, however it returns an error at line 26 (the beginning of the Ruby code).  Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the Ruby language. Do you know any source where i can learn it rapidly? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here it is: 

Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, => at line 26, column 8 (byte 537) after filter {\nruby { \n        init => \"\n           def split_str source, target  event\n               arr = event.get(source).split(\" \")  \n               arr.each.with_index(1) do |a, index|\n                   event.set(target+index, a)\n               end\n           end\n       \"\n       "

Comment: Can you please change this arr = event.get(source).split(" ") to arr = event.get(source).split(' '). Basically replacing double quotes to single quote.

Comment: That did it nitzien, but another error message appears (syntax error):
[ERROR] 2018-10-04 10:25:48.666 [LogStash::Runner] Logstash - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SyntaxError) (ruby filter init):2: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER
           def split_str source, target  event

Comment: That did it nitzien, great job! I don't see any errors regarding Logstash, I don't see the output to Kibana however. To what do you think this issue is related? Maybe the Ruby script is unable to put the new fields in place?

Comment: Can you please query data directly from elasticsearch?

Comment: It seems that no index is created after the import in elasticsearch. I'm trying to ascertain why

Comment: Hi, I managed to solve the issue. Trivially, the filename was not correct. However, Ruby throws an exception within logstash: [Ruby-0-Thread-7@[main]>worker1: :1] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: undefined local variable or method `source' for #<LogStash::Filters::Ruby:0x7950c81d>
Any hints?

Comment: My mistake. Try event.get('source').split(' ')

Comment: Error has changed: [Ruby-0-Thread-7@[main]>worker1: :1] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Hi nitzien, found a solution: it seems that the split method requires to cast the result of get.source to string (to_s.split). However it doesn't seem to output anything to a new field. How can this script be used?